# Prefetching solution for Safari browser?

Tags: html, safari, prefetch

According to this link [prefetch](http://caniuse.com/#feat=link-rel-prefetch) , prefetching is working only for specific browsers. Unfortunately for me, I need it to work mostly on mobile devices.

Anyone have a solution how to preload, prefetch, cache page so it works for iOS? (Safari)

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery mobile, here is the [documentation](https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-cache.html)
and here is the download [link](http://jquerymobile.com/resources/download/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.zip).

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but how does jQuery mobile solve the problem? For example, if I want to use prefetch to fetch audios or videos that may be added to the page (via JS functions) before they are added to the page, how does jQuery mobile accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

One solutions here is to go with base64 images.

Following links might be useful for further investigation.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme
[How to display base64 encoded image in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41053901/how-to-display-base64-encoded-image-in-html)

There are similar options with prefetch like "dns-prefetch", "preconnect" and "subresource" but support on IOS safari is not great(as of today).
https://css-tricks.com/prefetching-preloading-prebrowsing/

Answer (score -1):

Nowadays Safari mobile supports preload https://caniuse.com/?search=preload

Comment: @victorsc please read the full question carefully, it also includes preload: "Anyone have a solution how to preload, prefetch, cache page so it works for iOS? (Safari)"